# Authorize websocket connection with ws.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server

I'm currently trying to write a websocket connector between the server and one exclusive client for real-time information exchange between the two using ws.js. I would like that the server automatically asks the client for authentication what i have looks like this:

```
const ws = require("ws");
const pass = "1234"

class WebsocketHandler {
    constructor(port = 8080) {
        this.server = new ws.Server();
        this.server.on("connection", this.startHandleConnection.bind(this));
    }
    startHandleConnection(wsc) {
        this.wsc = wsc;
        //Authorize the client with a password before accepting the connection
        wsc.on("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this));
        wsc.send("Authorize"); // The client-side is expected to respond with the password
    }
    handleMessage(message) {
        if(!this.authorized && message !== pass) {
           delete this.wsc;
        } else {
           //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant approach to this?

Comment: Is there a reason why client cannot send credentials and use standard server on upgrade procedure? https://github.com/websockets/ws#client-authentication. Create connection and destroy it in case of unauthorization seems a bit risc to me.